# JavaFX GridLayoutPane with GridData.heightHint not updating unless Focus changes

Tags: layout, javafx, efxclipse

I created a `GridLayoutPane` and want to set the size of its children programmatically. This is working fine and the sizes are set correct,
but they are not applied after beeing set automatically.

My first thought was that I might have to call `.layout()` on the `Pane`, but this has no result at all. Now I noticed that my `heightHint` (on the GridData) do get applied when I click on a `TextField` after generating the `heightHint` (so changing focus does the trick)

I try to get a look into the world of `JavaFX`
`SWT` was my default for years nowm but for several reasons I try to port my widgets to `JavaFX`.

GridLayoutPane http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/doc/api/org/eclipse/fx/ui/panes/GridLayoutPane.html

is there a manual way to tell `JavaFX` to layout ALL nodes on a `Pane`?

- layout()
- layoutChildren()
- requestLayout()

have no result!

Comment: What is a JavaFX `GridLayoutPane`?

Comment: @James_D: Seems to be this thing here http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/doc/api/org/eclipse/fx/ui/panes/GridLayoutPane.html At least the constraint includes a `heightHint`

Comment: correct fabian, i should have mentioned that. -  added your link to the question